# Customize typing cursor in string

Tags: javascript, html, string

I wish to change writing cursor (While typing there is show/hide cursor) position in replace string.

Here is my string:

```
if(str.indexOf('<html>') != -1){
    str = str.replace(/\<html\>([a-z|A-Z|0-9| ])/g, "<html>\n   \n</html>");
}
```

That means when I typing `<html>` the result is:

```
<html>

</html>|
       ^
The typing cursor
```

Now the wanted result:

```
<html>
|
</html>
```

How can I customize/place typing cursor in replacement string?

Comment: Strings don't have cursors/insertion points. Are you talking about an HTML input of some kind? If so, what kind? `input[type="text"]`? `textarea`? Something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+set+cursor+position

Comment: I talking about textarea, and I meant to place the cursor (like i typing in this comment) In middle of the string.

Comment: Your own attempt will throw away the next character typed. And unless you build some shielding around this, you will gradually fill up your hard disk with the text "</html>".

Comment: You just set a collapsed DOM Selection on that DOM element to the desired position. That's where the caret will show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the JS Console on stackoverflow, after clicking [Ask Question]:

```
document.querySelector('textarea#wmd-input').value = "Here >< is your caret"
document.querySelector('textarea#wmd-input').selectionStart = 6
document.querySelector('textarea#wmd-input').selectionEnd = 6
```

For some element types other than textarea

```
element.setSelection(startPosition, startPosition)
```

might work.